# How to use Devise helpers in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer

I can use Devise helper methods in regular views but don't know how to use it within my Mailer. I need to determine if user is signed in to construct proper email message.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def receipt
  end
end
```

**receipt.text.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> #Error: undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<#<Class:0x35695fc>
    Secret link
<% end %>
```

Comment: Suppose, a user receives this email on two machines: on one he's logged in, on another he isn't. What do you do now? (*hint: proper email shouldn't depend on user's logged in status*)

Comment: Do you have a timestamp for the last signed in time? Devise can provide this. Then use Active Record to fetch that attribute and determine if it was in the last X minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you **can't** and most of all, you **shouldn't** use this kind of Devise helper on your mailer.

Why ? Well, if you search Devise's code base for the `user_signed_in?` helper, you will find it in `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` module, as you can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L44). This means that it is supposed to be used in a **controller context**, as it uses method such as `request` and `warden` that is only available on controllers.

If you must make any decision in your mail view based on whether a user is signed in or not, I would recommend you to pass this information from your controller to your mailer:

**Your controller:**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    UserMailer.receipt(user_signed_in?).deliver
    #....
  end
end
```

**Your mailer:**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def receipt(signed_in)
    @signed_in = singed_in
    #....
  end 
end
```

**Your mailer view:**

```
<% if @signed_in %>
  Secret link
<% end %>
```

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it over from helper. Something like this

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def receipt
    @is_signed = user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

and

```
<% if @is_signed %>
  Secret link
<% end %>
```